# Uploading several files

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example I have a model - Case. This `case` can contain no one or several pictures and no one or several documents. User should be able to add some pictures to this 'case'. Quantity of this files for every case is unknown. As I understand I should create a new model with case_id which will store these files - for example 'Picture'. As I understand the `paperclip` gem doesn't suitable for this task, because it works with exact quantity of files. In this case it is unknown.
In addition, there is yet another problem - in the time of creating a new case, this case is doesn't exist in database and I don't know how to create a new pictures in the time of missing of case (its id = null)
Can anyone give me some idea - about better way to solve this? Which plug-in or gem should to use or give me a references on some articles. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, use polymorphism and forms nested attributes.

```
class Case < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, :as => :imageable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures
end

Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures
  belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Read :

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html